# Hive : The application won't work without a running HiveServer2

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am new to this field. I was checking CDH 5.8 quick-start VM to try some basic hive/impala example.

But I hit an issue, while I am opening HUE it's giving below error. I searched solution for but didnt get anything which can resolve my issue.

```
 Configuration files located in /etc/hue/conf.empty

Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.

Hive    The application won't work without a running HiveServer2.
```

I checked the and it's up & running. Tried restarting the service & CDH, didnt help.

```
Hive Server2 is running                                    [  OK  ]
```

When navigated to Hive tried some command it gave me below error.

`Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:10000 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:10000',`)

FOR Impala I am getting

`AnalysisException: This Impala daemon is not ready to accept user requests. Status: Waiting for catalog update from the StateStore`.

Tried starting hive --service metastore but got error

```
[cloudera@quickstart conf.empty]$ hive --service metastore 
2017-03-03 05:37:14,502 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.
Starting Hive Metastore Server
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.
```

Not sure what is wrong  or if I need to change some config. Can you anyone guide me towards the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You HiveServer2 requires Metastore up and running. Seems your Metastore Server cannot start because the port 9083 is already used by some service. Check it:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 9083
```

If something is using this port you need to either change the port of you metastore in hive configuration or stop the application which already uses this port.

Comment: what output should we look for?

Comment: @thebluephantom you should have see a record in case if something using this port. There you'll be able to see the PID of the application. Then you can use ps command to understand more details about that application. You should either kill it and reconfigure to another port or you can reconfigure hive metastore to use another port

Comment: I think it can be many issues. I checked and found data block loss causing safe mode in HDFS. I cleared that, BTW due to blue screen on Win 7 affecting Linux VM. Then it was fine. @Alex